# VSFTPD allows root access despite being listed in ftpusers file

Tags: ftp, root, chroot, vsftpd

I've installed VSFTPD on a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04. The only significant changes made to `vsftpd.conf` are:

```
anonymous_enable=no
local_enable=yes
write_enable=yes
chroot_local_user=yes
allow_writeable_chroot=yes
```

VSFTPD should block root access by default, I've checked the `/etc/ftpusers` file and root is listed within the file to deny access however I am able to ftp into the server using the root account. When I do I'm taken into, and jailed to, the `/root` folder.

How can I disable root login via ftp?

Contents of `/etc/pam.d/vsftp`:

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required    pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required    pam_shells.so
```

adding

```
userlist_enable=yes
userlist_deny=yes
userlist_file=/etc/vsftp.user_list
```

did deny root access - but only if one there is only one line in the userlist file. If I add multiple users (one per line) then it breaks and allows root login.

If root is not being read from the `/etc/ftpusers` file then I'm assuming other users such as `mail`, `daemon`, `man`, `nobody` etc. aren't being read either? (Hence why I tried to add them to the userlist file)

Comment: check /etc/pam.d/vsftpd what's there. Also check auth.log.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the following is in your vsftpd.conf

```
 userlist_deny=YES
```

Then make sure root is in

```
 /etc/vsftpd/user_list
```

Restart vsftp and it should deny root login